# Javascript function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Error is:

> switchDiv is not defined

JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9s5Px/11/

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="foo">
        <p>Div A</p>
    </div>

    <div class="foo">
        <p>Div B</p>
    </div>

    <div class="foo">
        <p>Div C</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('.foo').fadeOut('fast');

var count = $('.foo').length;
console.log(count);

var currentItem = 0;

function switchDiv() {
    $('.foo').get(currentItem).fadeOut();
    if (currentItem < count - 1) {            
        $('.foo').get(currentItem + 1).fadeIn();
    }
    else {        
        $('.foo').get(currentItem).fadeOut();
        currentItem = 0;
        $('.foo').get(0).fadeIn();
    }        
}

setTimeout("switchDiv()", 5000 );
```

Answer (score 5):

Your string of code that you pass in to `setTimeout` does not have access to your local closure. It is being `eval`ed globally.

Pass it the function itself, not a string:

```
setTimeout(switchDiv, 5000);
```

---

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9s5Px/12/), no errors.

Comment: So without the parenthesis? Doesn't it need them as it's a function?

Comment: Your need parenthesis to call a function, not to pass it.

Comment: @AdamRackis - Thanks! Were you the one to take me over that threshold?

Comment: I was not, but I did send you to 10015 :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have a scoping issue in your jsfiddle. Not sure about the actual code, but since you are not showing how that js is being I called I assume it is the same problem.

Note that jsfiddle will execute the code you specified inside `$(document).ready()` handler (see options on top left), and so you switchDiv will be defined in there. Where as your timeout is looking for switchDiv on global object, and is effectively this `setTimeout("window.switchDiv()", 5000);`

The solution is to either pass function reference to the setTImeout or define setTimeout in the global scope like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/9s5Px/14/).

As a side note: The `get()` function returns actual DOM object. WHat you probably looking for is `eq()`, but note that eq is 1-based.

Comment: +1 Nice explanation, didn't realize that the code was running under a different context, `$(document).ready()`, from the options on the left...

Comment: @Xander The neat and confusing part is that adding `$(document).ready()` handler to jsfiddle explicitly will still work. That is because jQuery is smart enough to run ready handler immediately if the DOM is already ready.

Answer (score 0):

two issues here:

1.use

```
setTimeout(switchDiv, 5000);
```

instead of evaluating a string.

2.inside switchDiv, you used `get` function to return a dom element in a jQuery object, and thus the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods are not applicable.

Modified src:

```
$('.foo').fadeOut('fast');

var count = $('.foo').length;
console.log(count);

var currentItem = 0;

function switchDiv() {
    $($('.foo').get(currentItem)).fadeOut();
    if (currentItem < count - 1) {            
        $($('.foo').get(currentItem + 1)).fadeIn();
    }
    else {        
        $($('.foo').get(currentItem)).fadeOut();
        currentItem = 0;
        $($('.foo').get(0)).fadeIn();
    }        
}

setTimeout(switchDiv, 5000 );
```